# How to merge pandas dataframe into existing reportlab table?

Tags: python, pandas, reportlab

```
example_df = [[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5]]
```

I want to integrate example_df pandas data frame into an existing Reportlab table - where the number of rows is changing (could be 3 as shown in the example, or it could be 20):

```
rlab_table(['Mean','Max','Min','TestA','TestB'],
['','','','',''], 
['','','','',''], 
['','','','','']])
```

I have tried:

```
np.array(example_df).tolist()
```

but I get this error (AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'wrapOn')

I have also tried:

```
inputDF = example_df.loc[:,'col1':'col5']
rlab_table(['Mean','Max','Min','TestA','TestB'],
inputDF)
```

and only the header of the data frame appears, not the data contained within (even though when I print inputDF I can see all of the data listed).

I am able to manually add each row into the report lab table by doing:

```
rlab_table(['Mean','Max','Min','TestA','TestB'],
np.array(example_df).tolist()[0],
np.array(example_df).tolist()[1], 
np.array(example_df).tolist()[2]])
```

However, the issue is that the number of rows in the dataframe is constantly changing, so I am seeking a solution similar to:

```
rlab_table(['Mean','Max','Min','TestA','TestB'],
np.array(example_df).tolist()[0:X])] 
#Where X is the number of rows in the dataframe
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> rlab_table=[['Mean','Max','Min','TestA','TestB']]**+df.values.tolist()**

add the dataframe list outside the brackets (as in the bolded area above) is the solution to the problem (and super fast!)